# Can't assign Bool member of ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, boolean, viewcontroller

For some reason this prepare code for a segue crashes because newGridViewController is nil. Any ideas?

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: Any?) {
  if segue.identifier == "Grid" {
    if let newGridViewController = segue.destination as? GridViewController
      if savePhotoWithSlicer.isOn {
      newGridViewController?.savePhotoWithSlicer = true
      if (newGridViewController?.savePhotoWithSlicer)! { print("TRUE") }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: at first line there is `newGridController`, on the third one `newGridViewController`.. fix your code here

Comment: I would imagine that your downcast actually failed an `newGridController` is `nil` or `savePhotoWithSlicer`returned `nil`. Use an `if let newGridController=...` and get rid of the force unwrap

Comment: obviously `"Grid"` segue does not go to `GridViewController`.. check your storyboards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what the exception is, but I imagine that it is "unexpectedly found nil..." caused by the force unwrap on the second last line,

I suspect that the root cause is the conditional downcast to `GridViewController` failed, so `newGridViewController` is actually nil.  Since you use a conditional unwrap everywhere except the second last line, you don't get a crash until that point.

A better structure is to use an `if let...` conditional downcast:

```
if let newGridViewController = segue.destination as? GridViewController {
    newGridViewController.savePhotoWithSlicer = savePhotoWithSlicer.isOn
    if newGridViewController.savePhotoWithSlicer { 
        print("TRUE") 
    }
}
```

This will prevent the crash, but it probably still won't print "TRUE" as I strongly suspect that `segue.destination` is not a `GridViewController` - You need to check your storyboard and make sure that you have the right custom class for your scene.

**UPDATE**

Since you have now clarified that the segue leads to a navigation controller that embeds the `GridViewController` you can use this to get the desired view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Grid" {
        if let navController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
            if let newGridViewController = navController.viewControllers.first as? GridViewController {
                newGridViewController.savePhotoWithSlicer = savePhotoWithSlicer.isOn
                if newGridViewController.savePhotoWithSlicer { 
                    print("TRUE") 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I went to the Main.storyboard and checked that the segue does indeed go to a ViewController whose class is GridViewController. The caveat to that statement is that in between ViewController and GridViewController there is a Navigation Controller. Wold that change things?

Comment: It certainly will.  It means that the destination view controller is a `UINavigationController`.  The grid view controller is going to be the first element of the navigation controller's `viewControllers` array.

Comment: OK I will try to access, then assign the first element in the array. The whole point of this is to pass data into the second view controller GridViewController. If there's a better or cleaner way to pass data around please let me know.

Comment: Yep! Accessed the first element in my new navController.viewControllers[0] and that was my GridViewController that I could now assign to newGridViewController and push the data into its members that I wanted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is `let newGridController = segue.destination as? GridViewController`

My thought is your GridViewController is nil. Since you force unwrap newGridViewController in this line `if (newGridViewController?.savePhotoWithSlicer)! { print("TRUE") }` the code crashes.

Show us some more code to give you detailed explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Objective c and Swift will happily let you "assign" a value to nil, and that's probably what you are doing.  Just b/c you assign "true" to nil, doesn't mean you actually did anything ("true" just gets ignored).  So when you force unwrap the nil, you still crash.